# Best way to get the Biztalk orchestration source code from the exported MSI

Tags: biztalk, reverse-engineering

In one of my project, the developer forgot to check in the changes done to biztalk orchestration but the changes were delivered and installed in production server.  I would like to know the best way to get the Biztalk orchestration source code from MSI file/Biztalk.  I have read a thread about using a Decompile too but not sure how to get the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to BizTalk documenter for [2006](http://biztalkdocumenter.codeplex.com/), [2010](http://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/) (and soon to be released BizTalk 2013) and generate a help file that documents the Orchestration.

Update: Both of the version above are no longer being supported.  The latest versions of BizTalk Documenter for BizTalk 2006 through BizTalk 2013 R2 can be found [here](https://biztalk2013documenter.codeplex.com/)

Full Disclosure: I'm one of the developers on this new version.

Comment: Hi Dijkgraff, i have installed documenter however not sure how to get the .odx file.

Comment: Hi Dijkgraff, i see you have answered the question to extract resource files from the assembly for a similar poblem ; "You have several options

Use a de-compiler (such as .NET Reflector). You can then extract a string that is the contents of the ODX file as well as the XSLT for any maps. (I copied the string for the Orchestration out of reflector and pasted it into an empty Orchestration and re-created it). " however in my case i am not able to get the content , am i missing some details ?

Comment: The documenter won't get you the ODX file, but you will get a help file that documents it's code that will aid in re-creating it.  For the string in reflector I'll add the details to the other answer.

Comment: Dijikgraff, found the string values in source code ; it is in a different format with extra delimiters ; however it is good enough to recreate the source.  Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't decompile to the original Project, you can extract the 'source' files for the artifacts themselves.  They're included in the assembly as string resources.

So, once you find the Orchestration source, save that as a .odx in a new Project.

Update:
Note that

1. The ODX code will be in a private const string _symODXML.  Copy that string.
2. The string will has a lot of \n through it, remove those. After this it should be valid XML.
3. The string starts at `<?xml` and finishes at `</om:MetaModel>` whereas the ODX has some bits before and after that string.  So you need to paste into the ODX file so that you replace the central part that matches it in the ODX file and leaving the parts before and after it intact.

Comment: John, Thank you very much for your answer.  Since i am not too good at Biztak, i would like to know should i need to go to biztalk administrative console (connect to installed server) and search for this orchastration in resources section or do i need to extract the MSI and search for the orchastration to find the source code.

Comment: You need the compiled assembly (.dll), not the .msi.  You will find the assembly either in the 'install folder' if there is one, or in the Global Assembly Cache.

Comment: If you have the MSI you can also extract the DLL's from there by using this command 'msiexec /a <name>.msi /qb TARGETDIR=C:<target_dir>'.

Comment: Thanks All.  I have found the DLL and now trying to get the source code with a Decompiler too.